# Where is the documentation for the Page keyword?

Tags: apex, unit-test

In the documentation for testing controllers and extensions, there's a statement that references a `Page` object, but I've been unable to find where this is located elsewhere in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm). Where could I find more information on this object? In addition, what does Page.success mean?

Here's the example from the documentation:

```
public class thecontrollerTests {
    public static testMethod void testMyController() {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.success; // -------- What does Page.success mean?
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        thecontroller controller = new thecontroller();
        String nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

        // Verify that page fails without parameters
        System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);

        // Add parameters to page URL
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');

        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        controller = new thecontroller(); 
        controller.setLastName('lastname');
        controller.setFirstName('firstname');
        controller.setCompany('acme');
        controller.setEmail('firstlast@acme.com');
        nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

        // Verify that the success page displays
        System.assertEquals('/apex/success', nextPage);
        Lead[] leads = [select id, email from lead where Company = 'acme'];
        System.assertEquals('firstlast@acme.com', leads[0].email);
    }
}
```

Comment: The PageReference class has some information about it (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm). In your case, "success" is the name of an existing page. Taken from your link "The controller calls two additional pages: a success page and a failure page. The text of those pages is not important for this example. They merely have to exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all visualpages through the Page keyword,  Page.pagename will return a PageReference (url datatype with some extras) to the page.

You can also use it through Visualforce

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.otherPage}">
    This is a link to another page.
  </apex:outputLink>
```

As far as i know it is also only documented through Visualforce use under the [Global Variables](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm)

Comment: So, is "Success" the name of a Visualforce page?

Comment: Yes indeed it is. If you go to Setup > Develop > Pages you will see Visualforce pages listed with Labels and Names. Using this convention is good practice as the platform enforces referential integretity. Meaning if you attempt to delete the page it will stop you and inform you which parts of your code reference it. There are also benefits in respect to avoiding namespace issues when packaging and deploying your solution to this approach.

Answer (score 2):

- The [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm) topic in the Visualforce Developers guide covers **Page** from an Apex Controller perspective.

> Refers to a PageReference for a Visualforce page that has already been saved in your organization. By referring to a page in this way, the platform recognizes that this controller or controller extension is dependent on the existence of the specified page and will prevent the page from being deleted while the controller or extension exists.
>
> It's sister **$Page** feature for use in Visualforce page perspective is also described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm).
>
> **Best Practice.** In your case Page.success points to you having a page named 'succcess' in your org. If you go to Setup > Develop > Pages you will see Visualforce pages listed with Labels and Names. Using this convention is good practice as the platform enforces referential integretity. Meaning if you attempt to delete the page it will stop you and inform you which parts of your code reference it. There are also benefits in respect to avoiding namespace issues when packaging and deploying your solution to this approach.

Comment: Yes indeed it is. If you go to Setup > Develop > Pages you will see Visualforce pages listed with Labels and Names. Using this convention is good practice as the platform enforces referential integretity. Meaning if you attempt to delete the page it will stop you and inform you which parts of your code reference it. There are also benefits in respect to avoiding namespace issues when packaging and deploying your solution to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm

Please refer first point on instantiating .

Page.success means a page with page name "success".Its just a page name which you previously created